# SpecFlow - one featuretwo data sets

Tags: c#, specflow

I have two data sets, I want to use them depending on which machine the tests will be run on. How to do this in specflow?

> Scenario: The user logs in using the confirmed account
> When Logging in to the account: user1/user2
> Then Login succesful

If the tests run on machine1 then i use user1 account, if they run on machine 2 i use user2 account. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish this. The easiest way might be to store usernames in a `Dictionary` where the key is the hostname, and the value is the username.

This involves 3 parts:

1. **Create a config class**

   ```cs
   public class TestConfiguration
   {
       private readonly Dictionary<string, string> passwords;
       private readonly Dictionary<string, string> usernames;

       /// <summary>
       /// Returns the test password based on the current machine
       /// </summary>
       public string Password => passwords[Environment.MachineName];

       /// <summary>
       /// Returns the test username based on the current machine
       /// </summary>
       public string Username => usernames[Environment.MachineName];

       public TestConfiguration()
       {
           passwords = new Dictionary<string, string>()
           {
               { "hostname1", "password1" },
               { "hostname2", "password2" }
           };
           usernames = new Dictionary<string, string>()
           {
               { "hostname1", "username1" },
               { "hostname2", "username2" }
           };
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Register this with the SpecFlow dependency injection framework**

   ```cs
   [Binding]
   public class SpecFlowHooks
   {
       private readonly IObjectContainer container;

       public SpecFlowHooks(IObjectContainer container)
       {
           this.container = container;
       }

       [BeforeScenario]
       public void BeforeScenario()
       {
           var config = new TestConfiguration();

           container.RegisterInstanceAs(config);
       }
   }
   ```
3. **Use TestConfiguration in your step definitions**

   ```cs
   [Binding]
   public class LoginSteps
   {
       private readonly TestConfiguration config;

       public LoginSteps(TestConfiguration config)
       {
           this.config = config;
       }

       [Given(@"the user is logged in")]
       public void GivenTheUserIsLoggedIn()
       {
           // Log in using config.Username and config.Password
       }
   }
   ```

If you need the user information in any other step definition classes, simply add a `TestConfiguration config` parameter to the constructor of that class. See [Context Injection](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Context-Injection.html) for more information on how to use dependency injection with SpecFlow.